# Pass URLs between php pages

Tags: php

I was wondering how I can pass a URL to another web page using PHP. I know if I were to use an HTML form I could have a hidden field with the value being the URL I want to get.

How can I pass the URL along to another page without using a form?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do? Are you using PHP to POST or GET form data from another page, or are you attempting to pass some information from page to page by the client?

Comment: You may use javascript or pass around the URL to all your links using GET parameters?

Comment: yes ,, you can make Query string to pass the data to another url ..

Answer (score 2):

If the page is your own, you could use a session variable.

More details here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp

Comment: session is the way to go. You'll need to initialize it with session_start(); and then you can just do $_SESSION['url'] = 'http://whatever';

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$_SESSION`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php), or [a cookie](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php).

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a server global variable which includes a referrer variable.

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

You can echo this and it will output the page which the user came from.

Comment: the question did not specify if the url to be passed is a referer, it could be any URL I suppose

Comment: Agree, and I thought of cookies and sessions as well whie writing.

Answer (score 1):

You could pass it using a get query,which is in a way form data, so i won't go into it
 OR a session variable. On the sender page

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['url']="http://site.com"
```

and on the receiver

```
session_start();
$url=$_SESSION['url'];
unset($_SESSION['url'])l
```

Comment: Can I use this with cURL? I intended to cURL a web page to get all the links into an array. Then I wanted it so the fetched links are the ones that will be passed into another cURL page.

Comment: you can actually. and pass it as a POST array. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: I wanted to make a mobile version of a forum I visit. The owner refused to create a mobile version so I decided to do it. Basically I was gonna cURL a page and scrape the links. Then based on the link scraped they click a generic link that takes the scraped link and then cURLs it

Comment: u basically want  to make a proxy. http://back-links.org/how-to-make-a-proxy-site/ and for code: http://code.google.com/p/php5rp/

Comment: No I don't want to make a proxy. I need to make a mobile version of this site.

Comment: what you are trying to do is called a proxy. You fetch content from a certain site and show it to the user. The difference is you are not allowing the user to select the site. Your site is still acting as a proxy, however

Answer (score 0):

You can initiate sessions.

Put session_start(); at the top of every page (normally by including a header or function).  The session_start(); needs to come before any HTML output.

Then on your referring page, you can save values into the session array:
$_SESSION['URL'] = "myurl.com";

On your second page, you can reference it just like any other variable:
echo $_SESSION['URL'];

Answer (score -1):

```
<a href="somepage.php?url=<?php echo urlencode("http://example.com/page"); ?>">Link</a>
```

`somepage.php` would then receive the URL in the variable `$_GET['url']`.

Comment: You need to be careful with gets and URLs.  Depending on what you're doing with your code, it can be easy to insert malicious code this way.

Comment: @phpmeh, Not any easier than with POST or any other data supplied by the client...